# Setting up Play Store on a Samsung phone from China?

Tags: samsung

My mum received a Chinese Samsung Galaxy Mega 5.8 as a gift from a friend.

Since google is banned in China, there're no google-related apps. Since I don't have the play store, I'm unable to get any apps on it.

The browser version of the play store doesn't work either.

When I try to search for it on google, I never got an official link.

Is there any way I can get it without rooting?

Comment: Try to install apps via computer. I doubt this work. Maybe flashing another custom rom will do the job :D

Answer (score 1):

## Find a Play Store APK

You can Google `play store apk` or something similar, find a suitable (trustworthy!) source like [this one](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1996995) and sideload the APK.

This does not require you to be rooted, or your bootloader to be unlocked, but it does require you to allow installation of apps from unknown sources (check your *Security* settings or equivalent)

## Flash Google Apps

There are Google App zips for different Android versions you can flash. You can find these by Googling (again!) on reputable websites such as the [CyanogenMod wiki page](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Google_Apps). Pick the correct version that corresponds to your version of Android and flash it over your existing ROM. This will install the entire suite of Google Apps depending on which version you flash. Micro for the minimal amount of apps and full zip for everything Google.

However, this requires you to be rooted and have a custom recovery installed, so the first option might be preferable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I sideloaded the Play Store APK. However, when I try to open the app after installation, a blank app opens and closes immediately.